# How to set integer tag to a widget in xml layout file?

Tags: android, layout, tags

I have simple layout, but I can only set string tag. How to set integer tag?

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:tag="1"
  android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

---

UPDATE

I found out how to set Integer tags in xml layout. We need to specify an integer variable in any xml resource file. That should look like that:

res/values/value.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<integer name="int1">15</integer>
<integer name="int2">1</integer>
</resources>
```

And now we are free to use "@integer/int1" or "@integer/int2" as tags for our xml widgets, for example:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:tag="@integer/int2"
android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

However, in my case I preferred to set tag programmatically :)

Comment: can you explain little bit more about your intention ?

Comment: At present, when I use View.getTag(), I get String "1". What should I specify in xml layout to get Integer 1 instead of String "1"?

Comment: I can add id attribute to ImageView
, get it in code and use View.setTag(1), but I want to know how to set integer tag in xml layout file.

Comment: You can not set tag as integer in XML.

Comment: View.setTag(1) works in code because it takes 1 as object to tag.

Comment: so you have to set integer value same like your code android:tag="1"

Comment: @integer/int2 doesn't work for me, maybe it's a version of Android issue? (I'm using Jellybean). I got a class cast exception for converting the tag to an Integer because it is actually a String. Integer.parseInt(String) will work too, so I am using that.

Answer (score 17):

In xml you can only set String. But in code you can use `View.setTag(int value);` because it takes Object. To read a value you need to cast it to Integer `int value = (Integer)view.getTag();`

Comment: this could be used in a loop (iterating through child objects) to generate the result expected in the question, thanks this worked for me.

Comment: Integer.valueOf(tag) should be able to read both without problem, allowing you to set a String value in XML and then write Integers from then on without concern about ClassCastExceptions

Answer (score 4):

From the author's edit I attempted to use `@integer/int2` to set the tag as an integer, but it still seems that `getTag()` is returning the tag as a `String` (at least in Jellybean). `Integer.parseInt(String)` can convert a `String` to an `Integer` and `@integer/int2` can validate that your tag is a proper `Integer`. So if you want to put an `Integer` in a tag through XML that is probably the best route. Downside, since it uses `parseInt` it likely takes a little more time than having it stored as a int the whole time.

Comment: dont bother about performance of parseInt() which is nth of nth times better than inflating a layout :)

Comment: @comeGetSome I'm not worried, just mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following to setup the tag in xml and handle it later in code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="item_tag">1</string>
</resources>

<!-- TextView with Tag -->
<TextView
android:id="@+id/item_with_tag"
android:tag="@string/item_tag"/>

// retrieve the tag
int itemTag = Integer.valueOf((String) textView.getTag()); // itemTag == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Supply a tag for this view containing a String, to be retrieved later with `View.getTag()` or searched for with `View.findViewWithTag()`.

Must be a string value, using `'\\;'` to escape characters such as `'\\n'` or `'\\uxxxx'` for a unicode character.

For more information go to [android:tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atag)